# Use pgfplots to plot a single column .txt file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, tikz-datavisualization

I have a single column .txt file with the following info in it

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I use the following ME and it does no work:

```
\documentclass[border=1]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
            \addplot table {TestTable.txt};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where TestTable.txt contains as a single column the above numbers.

I would like to plot this using `pgfplots` (this is just an example so the result is a trivial line). The result should be a straight line of course (e.g. `y=x`). 
Hopefully the answer should also be applicable to a larger sample.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you expect that straight line to be the result. How are pair of points produced from your single column table?

Comment: the "x values" should be from 1 to 5 hence I expect a tilted straight line.

Comment: "1 to 5" as in the row number or the value read in the column? In the  latter case the correct answer is the one from Gonzalo

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate Please, next time state your problem clearly and correctly so people don't have to guess what you want.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina OK fair enough. I should have been more clear. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the row index as x coordinate you can use the key `x expr` together with the macro `\coordindex` (but since this starts from 0, you must add 1). Then, to use the value in the single column as y coordinate, you need `y index=0`. Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=1]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
            \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex+1, y index=0]
              {TestTable.txt};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I think probably this is more what OP was expecting. I'll delete my answer.